# Parse JS ACL - getPublicReadAccess for Parse.User.current() always returning false?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parse-platform, acl

I'm attempting to do the following in my view:

```
<option data-ng-selected="userACL.getPublicReadAccess()">Public</option>
```

and I can't seem to get the full ACL list for the Parse.User.current() - it always returns an ACL with read/write *only* for the current user. Here's the code from the controller (the project is in angularjs)

```
$scope.userACL = new Parse.ACL(Parse.User.current());
console.log($scope.userACL.toJSON());
```

the output of that toJSON returns an object with the current user id, and the properties of read: true, and write: true

[image: Console output for user]

but what I can't seem to get is the publicReadAccess for the user... which, I can see through the Parse dashboard to be public
[image: Parse Dashboard with private and public users]

I feel like I'm either going about this wrong, or misconstruing how the ACL should be used (in my mind, _User contains data that can be either public or private to the single user) Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Of course, writing out the question helped me solve it!

The answer is by creating a *new* ACL object, it was assigned a new list (of just the _User object) in the constructor for that _User object as [the documentation says it will](https://parse.com/docs/js/api/symbols/Parse.ACL.html#constructor)

The simple solution is to use Parse.Object **.getACL()** to retrieve the existing ACL for the _User object *facepalm*